# Why season the meat "liberally"?

Tags: seasoning

Whenever I watch cooking shows on TV, they always advise to season the meat "liberally", even "aggressively". Is there a particular reason for this, or do regular people just tend to under season their meat?

Comment: Simple; stop watching TV, and cook stuff the way you like :-)

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to steaks, there is specific reason to use a lot of salt.  [The Serious Eats food lab](http://www.seriouseats.com/2011/03/the-food-lab-more-tips-for-perfect-steaks.html) goes into pretty good detail about salting a steak.  It has to do with drawing out the moisture on the surface of the steak.  This helps create a nice sear and affects the way the steak cooks.

For other types of meat, I assume they are just telling everyone to season more.  The amount of salt used in a commercial kitchen is unreal.

Comment: Depending on how you are cooking, a great majority of the seasoning can easily fall off into the grill, stick to the pan, or other similar fates. You can avoid the over-salt by going with high quality seasonings, such as Spike or Mrs. Dash, or just rolling your own out of herbs and spices.